# What are compound types?

Tags: c++, types

My question is about composite types. I can't seem to find anywhere that explains what compound types are in C++.

Are they different from composite types?

Comment: There's a section "Compound Types" in the C++ standard `[basic.compound]`

Comment: You sound like another victim of substandard books/ university syllabus. These books/universities make up their own terms which have no standard definition. Please stay away from such materials.

Comment: @sid-m: These terms are used by the Standard.  I agree with staying away from textbooks that use a different definition, but there's no evidence of that here.

Comment: @BenVoigt the current draft only uses "composite" in the term "composite pointer type" in [expr.type/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#4)

Comment: @Swordfish: Yes, that's what it means in the Standard (One could also talk about a composite reference type, because all the rules not relating to `nullptr` apply just fine, but the Standard only uses "composite type" with pointers)

Comment: @jww where are you reading the term compund types?

Answer (score 5):

From the C++ working draft (N4713):

> **6.7 Types [basic.types]**
>
> 1. There are two kinds of types: fundamental types and compound types.

There is no specific definition of compound types in the said draft. All we are told is how these compound types are constructed.

> **6.7.2 Compound types [basic.compound]**
>
> 1. Compound types can be constructed in the following ways:
>    (1.1) — arrays of objects of a given type;
>    (1.2) — functions, which have parameters of given types and return void or references or objects of a given type;
>    (1.3) — pointers to cv void or objects or functions (including static members of classes) of a given type;
>    (1.4) — references to objects or functions of a given type. There are two types of references:
>    (1.4.1) — lvalue reference
>    (1.4.2) — rvalue reference
>    (1.5) — classes containing a sequence of objects of various types, a set of types, enumerations and functions for manipulating these objects, and a set of restrictions on the access to these entities;
>    (1.6) — unions, which are classes capable of containing objects of different types at different times;
>    (1.7) — enumerations, which comprise a set of named constant values. Each distinct enumeration constitutes a different enumerated type;
>    (1.8) — pointers to non-static class members, which identify members of a given type within objects of a given class. Pointers to data members and pointers to member functions are collectively called pointer-to-member types.

In the same draft composite types refer to composition of primary types in the form of templates.

> **23.15.4.2 Composite type traits [meta.unary.comp]**
>
> 1. These templates provide **convenient compositions of the primary type categories**, corresponding to the descriptions given in subclause 6.7.

Answer (score 5):

From the book *C++ Primer, 5th edition*:

> A compound type is a type that is defined in terms of another type. C++ has several compound types, two of which, **references and pointers...**

I think it means compound types are types like references and pointers. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Any type that is not a [fundamental type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) (a type in the core language) is a compound type.

Fundamental types: void, nullptr_t, bool, integer/character/floating-point types, ranges (C++20)
Compound types: All other types

Another way to think about this is that an object is a compound type if you have to use another type when writing it's declaration:

```
std::vector<T> myVec; // type T used in type std::vector<T> => compound
int* myPtr; // type int used in type int* => compound
double myVal = 10.3; // double is a fundamental type => fundamental
double& myRef = myVal; // type double is used in type double& => compound
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types :

Base type: like int,double,boolean ,... in addition this type can be qualified by const
`const int c1=89;`

compound type: Types that is built by using base type.
1- pointers `int *v1=&v1;`
2-references `int &r1=v1;`
3-arrays based on int or char our whatever
4-strings

this is how i understand it ,will be happy if someone can add or correct me.